# Modify object in container without pointer: vector vs set

Tags: c++, vector, reference, set

I have access to a factory which produces objects in the following way:

```
A a = factory.build();
```

I want to store objects of type `A` in a container, access them, modify their inner state and the next I access the object via the container I'd like to access the same as object as before (with the modified state). 
My first thought was to store pointers to `A` in a container. However, as given above, the factory does not give me a pointer to an object but the object itself.

Class A:

```
class A
{
  private:
    int id;

  public:
    A(int id)
    {
      this->id = id;
    }

    int getId() const
    {
      return id;
    }

    void setId(int id)
    {
      this->id = id;
    }
};
```

I figured out that the following works using `vector`:

```
A obj1(1);

std::vector<A> vec;
vec.push_back(obj1);

A & obj = vec[0];
obj.setId(4);

for(std::vector<A>::iterator itr = vec.begin();itr!=vec.end();itr++)
{
    std::cout << (*itr).getId() << endl;
}
```

This prints the modified id: 4.

Is something similar possible using `std::set`? I tried the following:

```
struct AComp
{
  bool operator()(const A lhs, const A rhs) const
  {
    return (lhs.getId() < rhs.getId());
  }
};
```

and

```
A obj2(1);

std::set<A, AComp> mySet;
mySet.insert(obj2);

int id = 1;
auto result = std::find_if(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), [id](A a) {return a.getId() == id;});

A tmp = *result;
tmp.setId(4);
std::cout << tmp.getId() << endl;

for(std::set<A>::iterator itr = mySet.begin(); itr!=mySet.end();itr++)
{
    std::cout << (*itr).getId() << endl;
}
```

Of course this does not change the state of the object in the set. But here I can't say

```
A & tmp = *result;
```

This gives me:

```
binding ‘const hallo2::A’ to reference of type ‘hallo2::A&’ discards qualifiers
```

How would I achieve this with a `std::set`?

Comment: If you are asking if you can modify objects contained in a set, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `*result` is a `const A&` which means you're not allowed to modify the object through this reference.

That's because you aren't allowed to modify objects in a set. If you really want to, then you have to remove and re-insert the object.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason behind it being allowed in `vector`, but disallowed in `set`?

Comment: Changing the values of things in a vector cannot invalidate the vector itself. Changing values of things in a set, which is almost always implemented as a balanced binary tree, can invalidate the tree, and thus the set.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the the factory class or build method so I have to assume you are referring to the standard patterns.

But, if all you need is a pointer to the object, something like this should do:

Aptr *A;

Aptr aptr = &(factory.build());

Comment: But the object from `factory.build()` is not created on the heap, so when when leaving the scope within `factory.build()` was called this object is destroyed, is it not?

Comment: A good question. I do not know. It would depend on how it was implemented and that code was not provided.